# Prestashop 1.7.7.1: override controller

Tags: overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In the past I made an override of AdminOrdersController to extract some orders from database of a given provider. I created this override into override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php. That was in Prestashop 1.6. Now the customer has updated the Prestashop version to 1.7.7.1 the override has stopped working. The controller AdminOrdersController in the new version no longer exists. Where I have to create this override to restart working?

Answer (score 1):

In Prestashop 1.7 you would have to do like described here, [Prestashop devdocs](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/override-decorate-controller/)

Note that overrides are not recommended, like you recently discovered, the preferred ways are extending or decorating.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm going to have a look.